# Change hostname only for apache2?

Tags: pi-4, apache-httpd, dns

I'm just running a website on my local network, and I want to change the hostname (because it's run on <HOSTNAME>.local), but I only want to change the hostname for the local domain name, not for everything. Is there a way to only change it for the local website domain without local dns? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hostname has nothing to do with Apache2,

Apache listen to what is coming in to the IP address that it has on its interface.

Depending on the http(s) request it send the request to the correct virtual host in apache2.

And the key value is `ServerName`, see example below and if you omit the `ServerName` it will be the same as wildcard.

The first virtual host is listening to two IP adr. and the name [www.example.org](http://www.example.org), the second example is listening on just oneIP adr. and the name [www.example.net](http://www.example.net)

**Example:**

```
<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40 172.20.30.50>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
    **ServerName www.example.org**
    # ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example3"
    **ServerName www.example.net**
    ServerAlias *.example.net
    # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

So to simplify it, it is apache2 who decide where the incoming http(s) traffic should be directed, not the system hostname!

And it is the DNS or hostfile on the local computer that directs where a http(s) traffic should be sent.

Answer (score 1):

Hostname is global. You can't have two names at the same time.
The host name is (user) set on `/etc/hostname` and also `/etc/hosts` (with localhost as alias).
The current active name is stored at kernel level on `/proc/sys/kernel/hostname`.
You can force your **dhclient** to publish a different name editing `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` and adding the following:

```
send host-name "<YOUR HOST NAME>";
```

Comment: *"You can't have two names at the same time"* -> This is context dependent.  In terms of local DNS, you can have multiple hostnames associated with the system (or a remote one) by adding aliases to `/etc/hosts` (see `man 5 hosts`).  This only works locally, but for development that's fine.  Apache can then be configured to respond differently depending on the hostname in the request ("virtual hosts"): https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/  You can thus set an arbitrary hostname that will resolve to `127.0.0.1` and be recognized by apache.   None of this requires changes to `/etc/hostname`.